# Building a website for musicians to provide market statistics only, not selling music

Tags: music

Assalamua'laikum.
I am personally a software engineer who builds websites and applications for others. Someone I know has come with a proposal to compensate me for building a website that will get user statistical data for various musicians from YouTube, Spotify and other networks and present that to each musician. Basically it will show stats for the musician for how he/she is doing as far consumers on various networks based on the usage data. So this will **not** sell any music but only provide statistical usage data regarding the audience of each various within various network. Is this something permissible for me to work on and getting paid for as a Muslim as I am not composing or listening to or selling any music through the website? Please advise.

Thank you in advance and may Allah be pleased with you all for your efforts to help all the Muslim brothers and sisters.

Answer (score 1):

If Music is haram then assisting it indirectly is haram too.

> تَعَاوَنُوا عَلَى الْبِرِّ وَالتَّقْوَىٰ وَلَا تَعَاوَنُوا عَلَى الْإِثْمِ وَالْعُدْوَانِ
>
> Cooperate in righteousness and piety, but do not cooperate in sin and aggression.
>
> (المائدة  ٢)

Comment: This answer needs some elaboration, read [answer]. How come scholars allow working for a bank as far as one is not involved in riba? So indirect assistance to something haram is not haram by default. And whether or not music is haram is a well known dispute among scholars.

Comment: So will this be permissible then? Please help